# up-casting to template class using custom cast operator

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading, upcasting

I have a class inheriting from two classes, one which is my own base class, and a template class:

```
typedef typename cusp::csr_matrix< int,
                                   float,
                                   cusp::host_memory > csr_matrix;

class CuspMatrix
: 
  public csr_matrix,
  public Matrix
{
...
}
```

At some point, I have to do an assignment, which will copy the base class object from the host to the device like so:

```
cusp::csr_matrix<int,float,cusp::host_memory> A(4,3,6);
cusp::csr_matrix<int,float,cusp::device_memory> A = B;
```

but before I can do that, I have to upcast my **this** to its base class **csr_matrix**

I've tried with **static_cast** and a custom cast operator:

```
operator csr_matrix()
{
  return *( cusp::csr_matrix< int,float,cusp::device_memory> *)this;
}
```

However, when I try to do the actual thing, I get tons of errors from the compiler

```
cusp::csr_matrix<int,float,cusp::device_memory> mtx = *(csr_matrix *)this;
```

In fact, static casting also is beyond me at this point:

```
auto me = static_cast<csr_matrix>( *this );
cusp::csr_matrix<int,float,cusp::device_memory> mtx = me;
```

yet, a C-style shotgun cast without the typedef, seems to work:

```
auto me = *( cusp::csr_matrix< int,
                               float,
                               cusp::host_memory> *)this;
```

but fails with the typedef:

```
auto me = *( csr_matrix *)this;
```

- **So, How can I safely up-cast using my own custom operator, preferably by
  using a static cast?**
- **Why does casting with the full namespace::type work, yet fail with the typedef?**

Comment: Your class is derived from `csr_matrix<int,float,cusp::host_memory>`, yet you try to cast it to `csr_matrix<int,float,cusp::device_memory>`. That's not really upcasting -- it's casting to an unrelated type (as far as I understand).

Comment: No, the typedef is csr_matrix<int,float,cusp::host_memory>, but you're right the code above is wrong. The assignment from cusp::host_memory to cusp::device_memory is a different story, and can be done from one to another.

Comment: Regarding the typedef-based cast, i.e. `auto me = *(csr_matrix*)this;`: The problem may be caused by the fact that at this point in the code `csr_matrix` refers not only to the typedef-name, but also the original template name `cusp::csr_matrix`. This may be the result of class-name injection, combined with inheritance. Have you tried using a different name for the typedef?

Comment: No, I'll give it a try right away

Comment: No I'm still getting errors, albeit the reason may be different

Comment: Yes... actually, the typedef-based version should work (both using `static_cast` and C-style cast, and even without renaming the typedef). What error messages do you get for that?

Comment: errors from cusp, when doing the assignment operation. As if my typename is only locally valid?

Comment: Please paste the exact error message -- makes debugging so much easier.

Comment: @arne It was non-related, I was trying to compile and link cuda kernel code from a header file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cusp::csr_matrix<int,float,cusp::device_memory> mtx = *(csr_matrix *)this;
```

This cast can never call a conversion function because the type of the operand `this` of the cast expression is `CuspMatrix*`. A conversion function will only be considered when the type of the operand is a class type:

```
cusp::csr_matrix<int,float,cusp::device_memory> mtx = (csr_matrix)*this;
```

In this scenario, csr_matrix is already a public base class of `CuspMatrix` - so the conversion function `CuspMatrix::operator csr_matrix()`, can never be called.

This upward-conversion does not require a cast - when `this` is of type `CuspMatrix*` and `cusp::csr_matrix<int,float,cusp::device_memory>` supports assignment from `cusp::csr_matrix<int,float,cusp::host_memory>`, you should be able to do this:

```
cusp::csr_matrix<int,float,cusp::device_memory> mtx = *this;
```

Without seeing the actual error messages and a compilable example, it's difficult to answer the second question.

Comment: So an implicit cast should work just fine? Bear in mind, the base class is cusp::csr_matrix<int,float,cusp::host_memory> the assignment you are doing above is copying from one type to another, but I'm guessing you meant the host_memory template param.